# Добавить элемент в массив си

Tags: c, массивы

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int A[] = {1,3,5,7,8};
    int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
    int i = 0, j = n;

    printf("The original array: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("A[%d] = %d \n", i, A[i]);
    }
    n = n + 1; // Увеличиваем счетчик на единицу
    
    while (j >= k) { //Пока j не станет больше или равен к = 3
        A[j + 1] = A[j]; // j элементу массива присваиваем номер j+1
        j = j - 1; // Уменьшаем индекс
    }
    A[k] = item; // 3 элементу массива присваиваем значение item
    printf("Array element after insertion:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("A[%d] = %d \n", i, A[i]);
    } 
return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте, попался такой кусочек кода, объясните пожалуйста. Массив статический, как добавляется элемент?

Comment: Создается новый массив на 1 элемент больше и в него переносятся элемента из старого массива

Comment: массив находиться в стеке рядом с другими переменными. при записывании данных за пределы выделенной памяти происходит порча данных и неопределённое поведение программы. Это происходит сразу `j == 5` , `A[j + 1] = A[j];` портит не свою память, прочитывая опять не свою память. Напоминаю, элементы в массиве находятся по индексам `0 .. 4`, а тут  делается первое присваивание `A[6] = A[5];` совсем не в тему.

Comment: Ну это понятно, но ведь работает. Не в каждом компиляторе  правда, но работает. Вот мне и интересно - почему?

Comment: используйте динамический массив и храните в куче